# Glassmorphism glitch

Tags: html, css, frontend, pseudo-element, blur

I am developing a website. I am using glassmorphism effect for navbar. Firsly i used backdrop-filter property for blur effect to my navbar but I was having issue that the nested elements like dropdowns in navbar were not able to have blue effect. After reading documentation I found that If we use backdrop-filter property for navbar than blur effect does not work for nested elements. Then the solution to this problem was to use pseudo selector for navbar to render blur effect. It worked well. But then i faced another glitch. When I resize my screen in inspect then blur effect only seems in a little portion of navbar. But on reload it covers whole width. I have attached the image to that glitch.
I have researched a lot but could not find the solution
[image]

```
.navbar {
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(
    90.39deg,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.61) 1.19%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100.87%
  );
  padding-right: 100px;
  padding-left: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 20;
  transition: height 0.4s linear;
}

nav::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
  background: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  content: "";
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

I have tried my solutions but could not fix them.